# A class that separatley creates a JTextField with implemented keyListener, however it remains undetected when called in this way from main function

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, textarea, keylistener

I wish to make a rough and ready load of  reusable swing classes to save a bit of coding and to recap on what I once new however I cannot understand what it is in my problem that is not working; apart from some fundamental basic understanding of course.

Now I have looked at lots of questions about focuses and implementing `keylistener`, I actually tried a combination of all other threads on this problem and still don't have the answer that works.

In the `Easyswing` class, I hoped to take advantage of java knowing which constructor to use to determine the component I got, please also suggest a better way of doing it if you know it

here is my main snippet

```
public class mainbox
{
    static Easyswing tix   = new Easyswing(300,500);;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(tix.getText());
}
```

And here is the Easyswing class:

```
public class Easyswing
{


String text;
int locationx, locationy;
JTextArea tarea;
JTextField tfield;
JScrollPane scrollpane;
boolean istarea;


//text on startup, size in rows, size in columns, is editable, might take advantage of different constructors to give different uses to this class outputting messages
Easyswing(String t, int x, int y,int lx, int ly){


//create and initialise text areas starting text, size in number of rows and columns 
tarea = new JTextArea("",x, y);

//create slight border to avoid text right on edge
tarea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

//adds the text area to the scroll pane
scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tarea);

JFrame frame1 = new JFrame(t);
frame1.setSize(x,y);
frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame1.add(scrollpane);
frame1.setLocation(locationx = lx, locationy = ly);
frame1.setVisible(true);

//if it is a text area then true
istarea = true;
}


//this will create a basic text input field
Easyswing(int lx, int ly){

    tfield = new JTextField();

    scrollpane = new JScrollPane(tfield);

    JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Write");
    frame1.setSize(250,75);
    frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame1.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame1.add(scrollpane);
    frame1.setLocation(locationx = lx, locationy = ly);
    frame1.requestFocus();
```

//HERE HERE THIS IS WHAT I DID HERE WHY DOESNT THIS WORK???
        frame1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

```
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            System.out.println("whut");
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    istarea = false;
}
```

Comment: OH FOR THE LOVE OF GOD!!!!!!!!!

Comment: _Oh for the love of god_, write an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). No need to invoke any god anyway. Forget about using KeyListener: switch to either Key bindings or DocumentListener